# How to use auto-layout to put things in a percentage of a screen size IOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib, landscape, launch-screen

So I am trying to make my launch screen for an app.  The launch screen is made up of 2 text boxes and 2 UIImageViews.

This is my sketch up of what it will look like
[image: Iphone Concept]
[image: Ipad Concept]

My problem is I can not get auto layout to work with percentages of the screen, instead it has these numbers that I dont quite know what to do with.  So while I know that the two image views are a 4th of the screen width from the edges I dont know how to put it their.  Also I dont know how to make the image size occupy the same ratio of space on all devices.

Could you please get me started on setting this up?

Comment: add an equal widths constraint from subview to superview and set a value in the multiplier field

Answer (score 2):

autolayout does not Have Percentage support but it supports Aspect Ratio.

> 1. you need to add one view and add your two imageViews and textFields add equal width and height constraint for ImageViews and same for TextField
>
>    > you can also add constraints to ImageView to expand in rest of space for that just add margin constraints and equal width and Height of ImageViews.
> 2. add aspect Ratio to ImageView's Width and SuperViews width as your requirement.
>
>    > you can add aspect Ratio with individually to width and Height.
>    >     here as you mentioned in que. you can add aspect ration 4:1 for 4th of the screen size.
> 3. do same for TextField.

if you still need help than tell me I can explain in depth with screenshot.

Comment: it will also works if you do not add a view mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am having trouble doing step two.  I dont know where to do that stuff

Comment: Just Select one View hold Control and drag on another view on which you want to create Relation for Aspect Ratio. and give value for Aspect Ratio or select Those two views and click on Pin option and select Aspect Ratio
you can also edit after assign constraint.